# How do I adjust my button dynamically which is below a view in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I have a view which consist of several Labels then after that one button outside of the view. The last Label text content is dynamic. It might get few lines of text which will stretch the Label.

I want my button to move according to the size of that Label text, but I am getting the button on top of the text.
Below is the image of it:

[image]

As you can see rest of the elements are not moving.
I am new to iOS and I don't know what to do in this situation.
Please help.

Edit 1:
After adding vertical spacing the views got distorted.

[image]

Comment: You need to assign vertical spacing constraint of you submit button and comment label from storyboard.

Comment: I tried but it made the button go up .

Comment: Add your view heirarchy of that cell.